# Am using the pumping lemma correctly?

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that the following language is not regular via the Pumping Lemma. But I'm not truly sure if I have done it correctly.

{L = a<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> | n>= 0 }

What I've done so far is the following:

s = a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup>

x = a<sup>2<sup>i</sup></sup>

y = a<sup>2<sup>j</sup></sup>

z = a<sup>2<sup>p-i-j</sup></sup>

thus xy<sup>2</sup>z = a<sup>2<sup>p+j</sup></sup>

which means that a<sup>2<sup>p+j</sup></sup> > a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup>
, making the language not regular

Am I doing it correctly? or is there something I have wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite, you draw the correct conclusion, but the reasoning is a bit off. The [Pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) states that for every regular language `L`, there exists an integer `p >= 1` where every string `s` of length greater than or equal to `p` can be written as `s = xyz` where the following conditions hold:

1. `y` is non-empty
2. The length of xy ≤ p
3. xy<sup>i</sup>z is in the language `L` for all i ≥ 0

Your first step is correct, s = a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup> is indeed longer than p. However, the pumping lemma states that s can be divided as `s = xyz` satisfying the above conditions. In other words, *there exists* a division of s as `s = xyz`, but you don't get to choose what that division is, beyond knowing that it should satisfy the above three properties.

In your case `L` is the language consisting of just a's where the number of a's is a power of 2. Now taking s = a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup>, we know that the next longest string in `L` is (a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup>)<sup>2</sup>. From there, if the first two conditions hold, it can be seen that the third condition certainly cannot hold for `i = 2`, since a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup> < xy<sup>2</sup>z < (a<sup>2<sup>p</sup></sup>)<sup>2</sup>. (In plain english, the length of xy<sup>2</sup>z is between powers of two, so it is not in the language `L` as it would have been if it were a regular language)

Comment: did you infer that $xy^2z < (a^{2^p})2$, because $(a^{2^p})2 = (xyz)^2$ or am I wrong?